# How can I feed an Xquery module with a global variable from main script?

Tags: css, xml, xpath, xquery, saxon

Currently I am feeding the name of 2 databases to my main xql file through an external variable. I would like to pass these values to any of my XQL modules.

For example, I could have a main script importing module "mylib"

```
     import module namespace mylib = "http://example.org/mylib" at "myLib.xqm";

     declare variable $dbName external; 

     $mylib:print()
```

Then I feed main script with dbName external variable, and it works, but I would like to pass it someway to my module

```
     module namespace mylib = "http://example.org/mylib";

     declare variable $mylib:dbName external;

     declare function mymod:print() as xs:string  {
         $mymod:dbName
     };
```

How can I bind the value of local dbName to the module´s instance $myLib:dbName??

I tried :

- Making variables in main file global, so they can be read by any imported module
- Declare same variables in module and try to assign them from the main class with something like declare variable $mylib:dbname := $dbname
- Declare as external uniquely the module vars, fetch the value from them in my main script, and try to read it from there

Any apparently easy solution for this?? Or will I have to define same value statically to any module?

Answer (score 1):

Why not pass it as an argument to the functions?

```
mymod:print($dbname)
```

Comment: because then  have to pass it to ALL methdods and I am wondering if there is an easz waz, speciallz if i would like some szncroniyatioon with something like an inner static var

Answer (score 0):

If your XQuery-processor allows partial application with argument placeholders, you could return a set of methods in a map, that have the `$dbname` argument already bound to them.

**Example Module**

```
xquery version "3.1";

module namespace mymod = "http://example.org/mymod";

declare function mymod:print ($dbname as xs:string) as xs:string  {
    $dbname
};

declare function mymod:items-by-name ($dbname as xs:string, $names as xs:string*) as xs:string  {
    collection($dbname)//item[@name = $names]
};

declare function mymod:get-bound-methods ($dbname as xs:string) as map(*) {
    map {
        (: return result of a function :)
        "print": mymod:print($dbname),
        (: return partially applied function:)
        "items-by-name": mymod:items-by-name($dbname, ?) 
    }
};
```

**Usage**

```
import module namespace mymod = "http://example.org/mymod" at "mymod.xqm";

declare variable $dbName external; 

declare variable $local:bound := mymod:get-bound-methods($dbName);

(: print evaluates to a xs:string :)
$local:bound?print,
(: items-by-name evaluates to a function with an arity of 1 :)
$local:bound?items-by-name("a"),
$local:bound?items-by-name(("a", "sequence", "of", "names"))
```

Comment: I have s similar problem: I want to pass an external variable (called it 'x') from the main module to sub module. The sub module use this external variable ('x') to build a global variable so I cannot send the value ('x') as a parameter. Is here a way to do this?

Comment: Xquery does not have true global variables. They are always module local. But if that is enough for your use case you can modify `declare variable $local:bound := mymod:get-bound-methods($dbName);` to just return the modified value instead of a map.